# Что представляет собой курсор в Windows?

Tags: windows, winapi, курсор

Что представляет собой курсор в Windows? Это окно, или, может он является просто рисунком в GetDC(NULL)?

Comment: думаю, правильно будет - это часть виндовой подсистемы, которая занимается отрисовкой окон.

Comment: @KoVadim, ну, короче это не для простых смертных вроде нас)

Comment: Все зависит от того, что Вы хотите сделать.

Comment: @KoVadim, просто интересно, как он устроен

Comment: есть часть винды, которая занимается отрисовкой окон (менеждер окон). Его задача, согласно z-order отрисовать содержимое окон на рабочем столе. Также он рисует курсор мыши. В старых версиях винды это была просто картинка. Сейчас, во времена directx и gpu я даже и не знаю.

Comment: @KoVadim, а, так всё-таки этим менеджер окон занимается.  Спасибо

Comment: Если курсор мыши Cursor то он аппаратный (или спрайт), на уровне расширеных возможностей видеокарты. Только при неустановленых драйверах он может быть програмным (gdi). Курсор для текста (Caret) - похоже отрисовуется програмно. Думаю что библиотекой user.